# Polynomial form of the Klein bottle

Tags: surfaces, klein-bottle

[Here on wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KleinBottle.html), I found the polynomial form and parametric form of the famous Klein bottle.

But when I put the parametric form in Eq.(2)~(4) into the polynomial form in Eq.(1):

```
klein = @(x, y, z) (x .^ 2 + y .^ 2 + z .^ 2 + 2 * y - 1) .* ((x .^ 2 + y .^ 2 + z .^ 2 - 2 * y - 1) .^ 2 - 8 * z .^ 2) + 16 * x .* z .* (x .^ 2 + y .^ 2 + z .^ 2 - 2 * y - 1);

fx = @(u, v) cos(u) .* (cos(u / 2) .* (sqrt(2) + cos(v)) + (sin(u / 2) .* sin(v) .* cos(v)));
fy = @(u, v) sin(u) .* (cos(u / 2) .* (sqrt(2) + cos(v)) + (sin(u / 2) .* sin(v) .* cos(v)));
fz = @(u, v) -1 * sin(u / 2) .* (sqrt(2) + cos(v)) + cos(u / 2) .* sin(v) .* cos(v);

u = 0;
v = 0;
X = fx(u, v);
Y = fy(u, v);
Z = fz(u, v);

result = klein(X, Y, Z);

disp(num2str(result));
```

Something went wrong! The result is far from zero (112.5685 instead!)

Why? Is there anything wrong with the equations on the website?